# Web crawler in PHP not able to create records in mysql database. How to fix?

Tags: php

I am creating a web crawler for a search engine like Google. The web crawler works well, that's what I see when I run it through terminal, but it is not writing any records in the mysql database.

I have already tried granting all permissions to the database user the web crawler uses, but it was of no use. My server is flawless, that I can be sure of.

```
<?php
$start = "http://localhost/mariophp/test.html";
$already_crawled=array();
$crawling=array();
function get_details($url)
{
    $options=array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET", 'headers'=>"User-Agent: ZeroBot/0.2\n"));
    $context=stream_context_create($options);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML(@file_get_contents($url,false,$context));
    $title=$doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
    $title=$title->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $simg=$doc->getElementsByTagName("img");
    //$simg=$simg->getAttribute("src");
    //$simg=$simg->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $description="";
    $keywords="";
    $metas=$doc->getElementsByTagName("meta");
    for($i=0; $i<$metas->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta=$metas->item($i);
        if($meta->getAttribute("name")==strtolower("description"))
            $description=$meta->getAttribute("content");
        if($meta->getAttribute("name")==strtolower("keywords"))
            $keywords=$meta->getAttribute("content");
    }
    $_con=mysqli_connect("localhost","augustus","password");
    mysqli_select_db($_con,"websited");

    $title=$_POST["title"];
    $url=$_POST["url"];
    $keywords=$_POST["keywords"];
    $description=$_POST["description"];
    $simg=$_POST["simg"];

    $sql="insert into websited(stitle,slink,skey,sdesc,simg) values('$title','$url',$keywords',$description','$simg')"; 
    if(!mysqli_query($_con,$sql))
       {
        echo "Error: mysqli_error($_con))";
       }       

}
function follow_links($url)
{
    global $already_crawled;
    global $crawling;
    $options=array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET", 'headers'=>"User-Agent: MarioBot/0.1\n"));
    $context=stream_context_create($options);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML(@file_get_contents($url,false,$context));
    $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach ($linklist as $link)
    {
        $l = $link->getAttribute("href");
        if(substr($l,0,1)=="/" && substr($l,0,2)!="//")
        {
            $l=parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"].$l;
        }
        else if (substr($l,0,2)=="//") 
        {
            $l=parse_url($url)["scheme"].":".$l;
        }
        else if(substr($l,0,2)=="./")
        {
            $l=parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"].dirname(parse_url($url)["path"]).substr($l,1);
        }
        else if(substr($l,0,1)=="#")
        {
            $l=parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"].parse_url($url)["path"].$l;
        }
        else if(substr($l,0,3)=="../")
        {
            $l=parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"]."/".$l;
        }
        else if(substr($l,0,11)=="javascript:")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(substr($l,0,5)!="https" && substr($l,0,4)!="http")
        {
            $l=parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"]."/".$l;
        }
        if(!in_array($l,$already_crawled))
        {
            $already_crawled[]=$l;
            $crawling[]=$l;
            echo get_details($l)."\n";
            //echo $l."\n";
        }
    }
    array_shift($crawling);
    foreach ($crawling as $site) {
        follow_links($site);
    }
}
follow_links($start);
print_r($already_crawled);
?>
```

Note:The test.html file mentioned in the code is a simple file containing links to different websites.
You may need to setup a server first to successfully run this code.
I am getting the following output right now.
     [augustoandro@Augustus zerophp]$ php crawle2.php
     PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 30
     PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 31
     PHP Notice:  Undefined index: keywords in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 32
     PHP Notice:  Undefined index: description in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 33
     PHP Notice:  Undefined index: simg in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 34
     PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 39
     [augustoandro@Augustoandro zerophp]$

Please help.

Comment: you don't try to insert anything in to a database in the above code. `$sql` is your query in a string, you don't do anything with it

Comment: @tim The name of my database and the table within it is the same, that is, "websited".

Comment: you need to the the wuery with `mysqli_query` ie `if(!mysqli_query($_con,$sql)){  echo("Error : " . mysqli_error($_con));
  }`

Comment: Nothing gets executed after a `return` statement.

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by concatenating strings. Create an array and use `json_encode()`.

Comment: Why does this statement make me nervous: _'My server is flawless, that I can be sure of.'_?

Comment: Why did you get rid of the `return` statement? Now what is `echo get_details($l)."\n";` supposed to print? The `return` should be at the end of the function, not the middle.

Comment: @ReddHerring  I am hosting another website on my server using php with a mysql database and it works perfectly.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is obvious. You never call `mysqli_query()` to execute the SQL. Just add that line and you should be fine.

Comment: @Barmar  I want the program to enter records in mysql database, therefore I removed the return statement since I don't have need of it now.

Comment: But you're going to insert the same row for every web site you crawl, since the `$_POST` variables are not dependent on the site being crawled.

Comment: @august No server is flawless. If you think that then your complacency opens up a channel for attack that you haven't considered.

Comment: I just made a change(added mysqli_query) in the above code, as you may have noticed, and I get the following output.

Comment: [augustoandro@Augustus zerophp]$ php crawle2.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 30
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 31
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: keywords in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 32
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: description in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 33
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: simg in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 34
PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /srv/http/zerophp/crawle2.php on line 39

Comment: You'ver overwriting the `$url`, `$description` and `$title` variables that you get from crawling with the values from `$_POST`.

Comment: Those errors mean that there's no `$_POST['url']`, `$_POST['keywords']`, etc. Are you executing this script from a form submission?

Comment: If you're running the script from the terminal, there are no `$_POST` parameters. Those come from submitting a form through a webserver. Why do you have lines like `$url = $_POST['url'];` if you're executing from the terminal?

Comment: You don't need to use either of them. You're setting the variables from the web page that you're scraping, not from user input.

Comment: @Barmar The answer you gave solved the problem partially but I am getting a new error now. I have pasted the new output in the question, please take a look and thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What is on line 34? It will happen if you try to use `$_con` in a place that expects a string, like `echo $_con;`.

Comment: What happened to the lines that I mentioned in my answer? How is anyone supposed to understand my answer if you edit the code to remove the problem?

Comment: @Barmar The mysqli_query that tim suggested before you.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I'll fix it right away.

Comment: I already fixed it. You didn't copy Tim's code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of these lines:

```
    $title=$_POST["title"];
    $url=$_POST["url"];
    $keywords=$_POST["keywords"];
    $description=$_POST["description"];
    $simg=$_POST["simg"];
```

These are overwriting the variables that you got from scraping the website. `$_POST` is for getting parameters that are submitted from a form or AJAX, they're not needed here.

The call to `mysqli_error()` should not be inside a string. Change

```
    if(!mysqli_query($_con,$sql))
       {
        echo "Error: mysqli_error($_con))";
       }
```

to

```
    if(!mysqli_query($_con,$sql))
       {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($_con));
       }
```